# WPF-Community MVVM Toolkit - Send Relay Command, to ViewModel, with DataGrid's SelectedItem as CommandParameter avoiding code-behind events

Tags: wpf, datagrid, relaycommand, commandparameter, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am stuck here and I can not find anything similar!!
In a WPF application and Community MVVM Toolkit, I have

DashBoard.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyIatreio.MVVM.Views.DashBoard"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyIatreio.MVVM.Views"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:nacontrols="clr-namespace:MyIatreio.NAControls"
        xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:MyIatreio.MVVM.ViewModels"
        xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MyIatreio.MVVM.Converters"
        Title="DashBoard"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:DashBoardViewModel}"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        WindowState="Maximized"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Window.Resources>
        <converters:DataGridRowToVisitConverter x:Key="DataGridRowToVisit" />
    </Window.Resources>
 
    <Grid>

        <DataGrid x:Name="VisitsDataGrid"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                  CanUserAddRows="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Visits, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedVisit, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  SelectionChanged="VisitsDataGrid_SelectionChanged"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  DataContext="{Binding}">

            <DataGrid.Resources>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="RowContextMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding EditVisitCommand}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                    <!--  Your ContextMenu Items  -->
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.Resources>

            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource RowContextMenu}" />
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

DashBoard.xaml.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using MyIatreio.MVVM.Messages;
using MyIatreio.MVVM.Models;
using MyIatreio.MVVM.ViewModels;
using MyIatreio.Utils.Dialogs;
using Syncfusion.Data.Extensions;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace MyIatreio.MVVM.Views;

public partial class DashBoard : Window
{
    private readonly DashBoardViewModel _dashboardViewModel;

    public DashBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _dashboardViewModel = new DashBoardViewModel();

        DataContext = _dashboardViewModel;
    }

    private void Close_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }

    private async void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await _dashboardViewModel.LoadData();
    }

    // etc !!
}
```

and in DashBoardViewModel.cs

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyIatreio.DataAccess;
using MyIatreio.DataAccess.Context;
using MyIatreio.DataAccess.Repositories;
using MyIatreio.MVVM.Messages;
using MyIatreio.MVVM.Models;
using MyIatreio.MVVM.Views;
using Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace MyIatreio.MVVM.ViewModels;

public partial class DashBoardViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork _uoW;

    // SelectedVisit
    [ObservableProperty]
    private Visit _selectedVisit;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private int _visitsCount;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Visit> _visits;


    public DashBoardViewModel()
    {
        SelectedVisit = new Visit();

        _uoW = new(new AppDbContext());

        Visits = [];
    }



    // EditVisit command with param either Visit selectedVisit or Object obj 
    // any of the following is accepted
    //
    // public void EditVisit(Visit visit)
    // public void EditVisit(Object obj)
    [RelayCommand]
    public void EditVisit(Object obj)
    {
        Visit selectedVisit = (Visit)obj;

        if (selectedVisit == null) return;

        // etc
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private void DeleteVisit(Visit visit)
    {
        Visits.Remove(visit);
        _uoW.Visits.Remove(visit);
        _uoW.SaveChanges();
    }

    // etc

}
```

I would like to avoid using events and the code behind.
I would like the viewmodel's EditVisit command to be called both when the user double clicks in a row and also when the user right clicks in a row and selects EditVisit on the ContextMenu that would popup!!

Several attempts made to manage to pass the DataGrid's selected row as a CommandParameter in the DashBoard.xaml file and send it to the viewmodel directly (not via code behind) but all failed. There must be a way to pass this selected row as a CommandParameter from within xaml only.

All I wanted from any of you WPF and Community MVVM Toolkit gurus is to guide me on how to pass the selected row (either as a Visit or as an Object) to the viewmodel

Can someone help me as I cannot find anything similar either in Google or in ChatGPT 3.5

Thanx in advance

Comment: The main problem is the `ContextMenu` as it is not part of the window and you cannot access relative or even absolute (with ElementName) members of the `DashBoard`. The `DataContext` is inherited and you can access the `SelectedVisit` property from the viewmodel => `CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedVisit}"`

Comment: I have a [sample app @github](https://github.com/SirRufo/so-77720663-MvvmToolkit) with the same `MenuItem`s in the Tool menu and context menu. The result of the command is visualized in the StatusBar.

Comment: I recommend that you get familiar with [Snoop WPF](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) where you can inspect your running WPF application for binding errors etc.

Comment: @SirRufo Your solution is working.But the context menu pops up even if the right click happens outside the datagrid rows, within the datagrid.  
To fix it I tried the 

 <DataGrid.RowStyle>
     <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
         <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource cm}" />
         <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                      Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick" />
     </Style>
 </DataGrid.RowStyle>

It seems to do the trick re: the correct popup but then its a disaster regarding the command and parameter DataGridRow misses SelectedItem

Comment: @SirRufo what I want to achieve is the VM's EditVisit(Visit v) relaycommand to be called when 
a) the user double clicks within a datagrid's cell (and only within it and not outside of them) and 
b) when the user selects the "Edit Visit" menu item from the contextmenu that would only popup in response to a right click within a datagrid cell (and ONLY and not outside of them). Hope to not have confused you. Can you or someone else help me further please? I would like to achieve this without using events and the code behind

Comment: You have not confused me. I only wanted you to show the problem with the context menu. I can not see why you are so afraid from code-behind. Some solutions need some coding behind the view

Comment: @SirRufo I am not afraid of it... It's much easier to achieve that using the code behind and events... I was just wondering why is it so hard to do something so so simple using xaml and community mvvm... Just disappointed So your suggestion would be to use the code behind avoiding the relaycommands Correct?

Comment: No, I use the commands to start an action in the VM but I execute the command from the code behind

Answer (score -2):

You need to associate your property with your command. Try the following:

```
// SelectedVisit
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(EditVisit))]
private Visit _selectedVisit;
```

I edit my answer for a correct answer:

```
// SelectedVisit
[ObservableProperty]
[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(EditVisitCommand))]
private Visit _selectedVisit;
```

Comment: MVVM Toolkit error MVVMTK0016
The target(s) of [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor] must be an accessible IRelayCommand property but EditVisit has no matches in type DashBoardViewModel
Confusing!!

Comment: Try changing the type of argument that the EditVisit command expects, you have it as object and it is expecting a Visit object.

That or your SelectedVisit property would have to be of type object.

I suspect that the types of the argument expected by the EditVisit command and the type of the property must be the same.

Comment: I have changed the EditVisit(Object obj) to EditVisit(Visit visit)
I also changed  
    [ObservableProperty]  
    [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(EditVisit), nameof(Visit))]  
    private Visit _selectedVisit; (<= here gives error)  
Not accepting it!!!  
  
 MVVMTK0016 The target(s) of [NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor] must be an accessible IRelayCommand property, but "EditVisit" has no matches in type MyIatreio.MVVM.ViewModels.DashBoardViewModel   

There must be an easy way get the SelectedItem from DataGrid and pass it as a parameter to the RelayCommand but my experties.... :(

Comment: Try put the property as public.

Comment: `NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor` needs the name of the command. `EditVisit` is the name of the method that will be called when that command executes. The name of the command is `EditVisitCommand` => `[NotifyCanExecuteChangedFor(nameof(EditVisitCommand))]`

Comment: Because of the code that he posted. EditVisit is the command. This method is decorated with [RelayCommand]

Comment: Editvisitcommand is the command. Note that greetuser is the method and greetusercommand is the command here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/relaycommand

Comment: Notifying can execute changed is not his problem here.

Comment: Andy, Thanks for the link,  Sir Rufo's answer IS correct